# Is this an error in Oppenheim and Schafer's Discrete-Time Signal Processing (3rd edt)?

Tags: transfer-function

[image]

Q: According to Fig 71, y[n]=something+e[n] and hence the transfer function from e[n] to y[n]
denoted as He(z) should be 1. Am I wrong?

Comment: is this a 1 bit quantizer?  a sigma-delta quantizer?  is $y[n] = \pm 1$ or $\pm \frac{\Delta}{2}$?

Comment: if this is a 1 bit quantizer, then the gain of the comparator is not 1 but depends on the relative energies or amplitudes of the input and output of the comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
Y(z) &= E(z) + \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}(X(z) - z^{-1} Y(z)) \\
 &= E(z) + \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}X(z) - \frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}} Y(z) \\
\\
Y(z) + \frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}} Y(z) &= E(z) + \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}X(z) \\
\left(1 + \frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}\right) Y(z) &= E(z) + \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}X(z) \\
 \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}} Y(z) &= E(z) + \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}X(z) \\
\end{align} $$

this results in:

$$ Y(z) = (1-z^{-1})E(z) + X(z) $$